# Keep headphone jack powered on android device, even without music playing

Tags: android, flutter

I recently installed a tablet in my car (370z) I love the thing but the only problem I have is that when music isn't playing I get a static noise buzz. After doing some research it seemed like its because in order to save power Android shuts off the power to the headphone jack. There's a launcher that comes with the setup I installed that eliminates this issue so I know it can be done. Unfortunately I don't like the launcher itself :). I want to build my own custom launcher for this but I don't know how to tackle this particular issue. I haven't not found any documentation on anything related to this anywhere. I'd appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Tablet Used: Samsung Tab A 10.1
OS: Android 11, not rooted (yet)

Comment: Have you tried playing an audio file that is recorded silence? Basically, if you want Android to keep the headphone jack powered on, you could have it play something, but something that does not interfere with whatever else you are doing with this tablet.

Comment: I thought about it, but I was unsure that it would mess up with playback coming from Spotify or other services. I'm unsure Android would allow to stack to players playing sounds coming from two different areas at the same time. I guess I'll test your suggestions and see.

Comment: "but I was unsure that it would mess up with playback coming from Spotify or other services" -- if you implement audio ducking, you should be able to stop your own playback, then resume when appropriate. This is the same technique that a music player uses to mute when a call is in progress.